# Using tableviews to display data from an array and getting error msg "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I'm new to iOS programming and I've gotten this error when trying to run my code.

```
[UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe65a0f0
```

I have two views in my project. The first view uses `JSONserialization` to populate a `tableView` with items.  And I use the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to send the corresponding objects to the next view.

The items are displayed fine in the first view, so far so good. But when I try to load the second view after selecting an item in the `tableView` it crashes and gives back the error written above.

When I set a breakpoint on `viewDidLoad` in `spelControllerView.m`, `kategorier` gets 3 objects but when it tries to count the array `kategorier` the error message above is thrown.

Here's my code:

1st view `ViewController.m` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
SpelControllerView *spelControllerView = [[SpelControllerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpelControllerView" bundle:nil];    
spelControllerView.title = [[jsonSnippet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CategoryName"];
spelControllerView.kategorier = [[jsonSnippet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Games"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:spelControllerView animated:YES];
```

2nd view `SpelViewController.m`

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
kategorier = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tableViewControl.dataSource = self;
tableViewControl.delegate = self;}
    - (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;}

    - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [kategorier count];}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

cell.textLabel.text = [[kategorier objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Games"];
return cell;}
```

`SpelControllerView.h`:

```
    @interface SpelControllerView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

UITableView *tableViewControl;
NSMutableArray *kategorier;}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *kategorier;
```

Thanks for your help!

Update:

This is my Json file.

```
    [
      {
        "CategoryName": "Arcade",
        "Games": [
          {
            "GameName": "Arcade game 1"
          },
          {
            "GameName": "Arcade game 2"
          },
          {
            "GameName": "Arcade game 3"
          }
        ], 
      },
      {
        "CategoryName": "FPS ",
        "Games": [
          {
            "GameName": "FPS game 1"
          },
          {
            "GameName": "FPS game 2"
          }
        ],

      },
      {
        "CategoryName": "Strategy",
        "Games": [
          {
            "GameName": "Strategy game 1"
          },
          {
            "GameName": "Strategy game 2"
          }
        ],

      },
      {
        "CategoryName": "C64",
        "Games": [
          {
            "GameName": "C64 game 1"
          },
          {
            "GameName": "C64 game 2"
          }
        ],

      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from viewDidLoad in SpelViewController:

```
kategorier = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You should not reinitialize kategorier after getting the JSON data from first viewController.

Comment: Tried to remove that line of code but still the same issue unfortunatly, i've added the json file in the question above

Comment: @engel Can you display the content of kategorier in viewDidLoad? See what did you actually receive from viewController. There seem to be errors in your JSON format. Try using http://www.jsonlint.com/ to validate.